# Get API Rest and past to Json + Html

Tags: html, json, api

I need help, I have an api and access key. "https://api-redemet.decea.mil.br/mensagens/metar/SBKP?api_key=XXXXX". When I call right into the browser it returns the information in Json.

I need to get a tag from the return calls "mens": that returns this updated data from hourly "METAR SBKP 290100Z 13012KT CAVOK 18/14 Q1020="

A friend helped me with another API of the same style where he created a local html capturing some tags.

Html that i use today.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
    <title>Metar</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
                setInterval(function() {
                    $.getJSON('https://api.radarbox.com/v2/airports/SBKP/metar', { bearerToken: "XXXXXXXX" })
                        .done(function(data) {
                        
                        var text = `<table>
                                        <tr style="background-color: #C4C4C4">
                                        <td><span style="color: rgb(255, 255, 0);"><strong>Metar SBKP ${data.apiMetar.observationTime}</strong></span></td>
                                                                                </tr>
                                                                        
                                                                            </table>`
                                    
                        $(".mypanel").html(text);
                    });
                }, 9000);
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="mypanel"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The new API returns:

```
{"status":true,"message":200,
"data":
{"current_page":1,
"data":[{"id_localidade":"SBKP","validade_inicial":"2021-04-29 01:00:00","mens":"METAR SBKP 290100Z 13012KT CAVOK 18\/14 Q1020=","recebimento":"2021-04-29
```

I need get this information "mens": **"METAR SBKP 290100Z 13012KT CAVOK 18/14 Q1020="**

and write to html changing ${data.apiMetar.observationTime}

Other question, first Api use  bearerToken and the new?

Api Information --> https://ajuda.decea.mil.br/base-de-conhecimento/api-redemet-mensagem-metar/

Tks for Help

Comment: To get the "mens" value , you can use data.data.data[0].mens.

Comment: i tried to inform so and also did not return

Answer (score 0):

Assume this is your JSON object

```json
{
    "status":true,
    "message":200,
"data": 
{
    "current_page":1,
    "data":[{
        "id_localidade":"SBKP",
        "validade_inicial":"2021-04-29 01:00:00",
        "mens":"METAR SBKP 290100Z 13012KT CAVOK 18\/14 Q1020=",
        "recebimento":"2021-04-29 
    }]
}
```

The updated code should be something like this:

```js
$.getJSON('https://api.radarbox.com/v2/airports/SBKP/metar', { bearerToken: "XXXXXXXX" })
.done(function(data) {

var text = `<table>
                <tr style="background-color: #C4C4C4">
                <td><span style="color: rgb(255, 255, 0);"><strong>Metar SBKP ${data.data[0]['mens']}</strong></span></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                
                                                    </table>`
            
$(".mypanel").html(text);
});
```

Comment: Hi Tony, tks for your help.

Comment: @EduardoCavallini Glad that I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help.  I'm not a developer so I get caught up with it kkkkkkkk

I changed my HTML with this call but does not display anything. I don't know if I'm passing the right call from api_key the old one was:
`$.getJSON('https://api.radarbox.com/v2/airports/SBKP/metar', { bearerToken: "ac3e1a8bXXXXXXX" })` and the new one from what I saw informs you directly in the URL , may be that I'm informing wrongly, I'm informing thus: `$.getJSON(https'api-redemet.decea.mil.br/mensagens/metar/SBKP?api_key=FEG1OXXXXXXXX'})`

Html is now:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
    <title>Metar</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
                setInterval(function() {
                    $.getJSON('https://api-redemet.decea.mil.br/mensagens/metar/SBKP?api_key=FEG1OXXXXXX'})
                        .done(function(data) {
                        
                        var text = `<table>
                                        <tr style="background-color: #C4C4C4">
                                        <td><span style="color: rgb(255, 255, 0);"><strong>Metar SBKP ${data.data[0]['mens']}</strong></span></td>
                                                                                    </tr>
                                                                                                                            
                                                                            </table>`
                                    
                        $(".mypanel").html(text);
                    });
                }, 1000);
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="mypanel"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```